# Can't implement options for Stanford CoreNLP's OpenIE annotator

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

I've been successfully running the Stanford CoreNLP annotators in Eclipse but have had issues implementing the provided options for the OpenIE annotator. Originally I thought it was an error only with the openie.filelist option and tried specifying the filepath different ways, but then I noticed that other options, such as openie.format, didn't work either.

Here is the code included below.

```
package main.java.com.nlptools.corenlp;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.*;

public class OpenIETest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Pipeline property setup
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
    props.setProperty("openie.format", "reverb");
    props.setProperty("openie.filelist", "src/OpenIETestDoc.txt");
    // Create corenlp pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // Build and annotate an example document
    Annotation annotation = 
        new Annotation("Usaine Bolt may play football trial in Australia. China's economic growth cools amid trade tensions. Trump is under fire after Putin meeting.");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    // Loop for each sentence in the document
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      // Get triples from sentence
       Collection<RelationTriple> triples =
          sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
      // Print triples
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) { 
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code, no error or warning messages show, only the relationship tuples formed from the example document. The expected output would be a TSV in ReVerb format of the tuples formed from the filelist I included. How can I get the added properties to work? Thanks for any help and/or insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for using the standalone OpenIE system are here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html

Those options don't work when using OpenIE as an annotator in a pipeline, they work when using the OpenIE's main() method.

Sample commands are at that link above.

```
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE  /path/to/file1  /path/to/file2
```

In Java code you should directly call OpenIE's main() method.

Comment: I see, thank you! The options definitely work from within a command line. This isn't entirely related, but is there any reason the options work when using certain other annotators in the pipeline, such as PaserAnnotator, and not OpenIE?

Comment: That is how the OpenIE annotator was implemented.  Though I should add some don't make sense in a pipeline.  For instance "filelist" doesn't make sense...you specify a file list for the entire pipeline to run on, so it wouldn't make sense to have a separate option for just one annotator.

Comment: Really, neither of the two options make sense in the pipeline. The output format doesn't do anything if you're annotating text, since it's not actually outputting anything. If you want to write a `RelationTriple` in ReVerb format (e.g., for the println in your code), you can use `RelationTriple#toReverbString()`.